# SAXParser encoding

Tags: android, xml, encoding, saxparser

I have a problem with encoding. To begin with perhaps a bit of code:

```
URL xmlUrl = new URL("http://helion.pl/rss/GW/promocje.rss");

SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();

Helion xmlHandler = new Helion();
reader.setContentHandler(xmlHandler);

InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(xmlUrl.openStream());
inputSource.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

reader.parse(inputSource);
```

The file is encoded ISO-8859-2, but when I use setEncoding("ISO-8859-2") file is not read. Please help.

DefaultHandler:

```
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        currentTagName = qName;
        if (TAG_ITEM.equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
            odczyt = true;
            element = new Element();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        String value = new String(ch, start, length);
        if (!value.trim().equals("")) {
            if (odczyt) {
                if (TAG_TYTOL.equalsIgnoreCase(currentTagName)) {
                    element.setTytol(value);
                } else if (TAG_OPIS.equalsIgnoreCase(currentTagName)) {
                    element.setOpis(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (TAG_ITEM.equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            odczyt = false;
            elementy.add(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Francis Upton mentions, characters can be called multiple times within one XML start/end element.
You should do something like this:

```
   @Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
String s = new String(ch, start, length);
            if (mTextBuffer == null) {
                mTextBuffer = new StringBuffer(s);
            } else {
                mTextBuffer.append(s);
            }
}
```

And then call element.setTytol(mTextBuffer)/element.setOpis(mTextBuffer) in your endElement method

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are setting it to `ISO-8859-1` which is very different, could that be the problem?

Comment: When I use ISO-8859-1 I get an incomplete text.
I should get:
&lt;a href="http://helion.pl/ksiazki/szastf.htm">&lt;img width="65px" align="left" src="http://heli......
I get:
/a>Nie mog3e¶ lepiej trafia! W tej ksi±?ce siedemnastu fotografów ....

Comment: When exactly happens when you set the encoding to be `ISO-8859-2`? If you are having problems with that, then show that as your example code, and explain what happens when you try it.

Comment: Please add the further information about what happens in your answer (by editing it) rather than the comments. The comments are too hard to read.

Comment: Cuts me to the text at the beginning:
&lt;a href="http://helion.pl/ksiazki/szastf.htm">&lt;img width="65px" align="left" src="http://helion.pl/okladki/65x85/szastf.jpg" title="Szalona strona fotografii. Niekonwencjonalne i twórcze techniki dla odważnych fotografów " alt="szastf"/>&lt;

Comment: Please show your SAX characters method. It's possible that that is incorrectly implemented. It can be called multiple times for a single element.

Comment: Beyond this, some characters are illegible.